# AJAX JSF selectItems in selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have  a **selectOneMenu** like this:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{beanBacking.pickedLongy}" id="foo" >
  <f:selectItems value="#{beanBacking.thisTakesAwhile}"/>
</selectOneMenu>
```

to populate the items in the select one menu it takes a long time, and my page just hangs there while it is doing this.

I have tried:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{beanBacking.pickedLongy}" id="foo" >
  <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />    
<f:selectItems value="#{beanBacking.thisTakesAwhile}"/>
    </selectOneMenu>
```

and it does not work either. Is there any way to load everything on the page and the items to load with ajax ?

Comment: You should be looking at revising your loading strategy. For example, your items could be loaded by an `@ApplicationScoped` or `@SessionScoped` bean, well ahead of when the component is actually ready to be rendered on-page

Comment: @kolossus how can I do that? I have a session scoped bean but the method that takes a while is on my main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up pre-loading the data by creating an init() method annotated with [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and performing the loading there. This way the data gets loaded when the bean is created and doesn't have to wait for a call from the page to be loaded.

### BEFORE:

```
private String longData;   


    public String getThisTakesAwhile(){

        return someClass.getLongData();

  }
```

### NOW:

```
private String longData; 


    public String getThisTakesAwhile(){

    return longData;
    }


    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){

    longData = someClass.getLongData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a deferred loading of your component.
And then cache the component.

```
<p:outputPanel deferred="true">
<p:cache key="selectOneMenu">
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{beanBacking.pickedLongy}" id="foo" >
  <f:selectItems value="#{beanBacking.thisTakesAwhile}"/>
 </selectOneMenu>
</p:cache>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Deferred loading will ensure that the page is loaded and the processing of the

```
<f:selectItems value="#{beanBacking.thisTakesAwhile}"/>
```

will continue in the background and it will render up once the processing is completed.

For cacheing the component your can use

1. [Primefaces Cache](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/cache.xhtml)
2. [Omnifaces Cache](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/cache)